# How to combine index arrays and slices in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a problem with a combination of index arrays and slices. I have an image (A) and a vector with positions/indexes (pos). Now, I want to select  slices (here 3x) from A at different positions. Instead of looping over the positions array, I tried to use the indexer functions (o1), but I does not work. 
Finally, all slices should be in one array (o2). 
Can you help me with this problem ?

```
A = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3],
             [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

# positions to select
# EDIT:
# pos = np.array([[2,6,7],
#                 [3,4,0]])
pos = np.array([[2,4,0],
                [3,6,6]])

# array with all selections
o1 = np.zeros((3,2,2)).astype(np.int)
# EDIT:
#o1 = A[pos[0]:pos[0]+1,pos[1]:pos[1]+1] ## this gives just one of the values in one area
o1 = A[pos[0]:pos[0] + 2,pos[1]:pos[1] + 2]
print(o1.shape)
print(o1)

# model result
o2 = np.array([[[1,1],[1,1]],[[2,2],[2,2]],[[3,3],[3,3]]])
print(o2.shape)
print(o2)
```

Another example: With the following line I get the area with the ones. Starting from the position [2,3] choose the next two rows and cols:

```
print( A[pos[0,0] : pos[0,0] + 2 , pos[1,0] : pos[1,0] + 2]  )
```

Isn't it possible to extend this to several position pairs (over the whole array pos[]) ?

Comment: If `np.array([[[1,1],[1,1]],[[2,2],[2,2]],[[3,3],[3,3]]])` is the expected o/p, could you explain how you got that using the inputs?

Comment: Your array is in 2 dimensions, why do you use np.zeros with 3 arguments ?

Comment: o2 is the expected result. As is mentioned, I have several positions given in pos[] and then I want to use them as index positions in A[] and extract 2x2 parts. In this case [[1,1],[1,1]] , [[2,2],[2,2]] and [[3,3],[3,3]]. All of them should be stored in a singe array (o2).

Comment: Shouldn't `pos` be `[[2,4,0],[3,6,6]]` instead?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Could you update the question accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`scikit's sliding window utility`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to extract such windows given the start indices from `pos` in a pretty straight forward way -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

out = view_as_windows(A, (2,2))[pos[0], pos[1]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [225]: A
Out[225]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [226]: pos = np.array([[2,4,0],[3,6,6]])

In [227]: from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

In [228]: view_as_windows(A, (2,2))[pos[0], pos[1]]
Out[228]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[2, 2],
        [2, 2]],

       [[3, 3],
        [3, 3]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want this:

```
A[pos.tolist()]
```

That is, fancy indexing using pairs of points.

Comment: Sry, I do not want just the singe values. I am looking for the whole areas. I changed the line in my first post.

Comment: @Jackster182: Your question is totally unclear.  Your use of example input data which is overly large and full of zeros does not help at all.  I have no idea what you're asking now.